# PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

Tags: python, pysftp

I cannot download packages from Anaconda cloud because of company policy with cloud downloads.  Therefore, I tried a workaround downloading the bioconda pysftp-0.2.9-py36_0.tar win64 version from Anaconda's website while not on the network and put it on my flash drive.  However, I am still getting a cannot found package error.  When I run the install code, I am in the directory that the tar file is in.

This code throws error below:

```
$ conda install pysftp-0.2.9-py36_0.tar 


Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - pysftp-0.2.9-py36_0.tar

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch

  Need help installing the package locally.
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a slight tweak to your command:

```
conda install --use-local pysftp-0.2.9-py36_0.tar
```

In addition, you'll need to put the downloaded file into

```
~/anaconda/conda-bld/<platform>
```

or something similar or specify an absolute path to the file.

I have this same issue at work.  In my case, they have a few proxy servers set up that I can point the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` to prior to running the `conda install <x>` or `pip install <x>` in order to bypass the issue.  Do you have anything similar?